# Solr indexing, split string field into list

Tags: text, indexing, solr, tokenize

In Solr, I want to index string field as list by splitting it.

Below is my indexing query in `data_config.xml` file.

```
<document name="Example">
<entity dataSource="example_table" name="Example" 
    query="select id, text from example_table"
    pk="id"
    transformer="RegexTransformer"
>
    <field column="id" name="id" />
    <field column="text" name="text" />
</entity>
```

Field `text` is a comma separated string. Example: `"A, B, C"`

Below is the field definition in `schema.xml` file

```
<field name="text" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="true" />
```

When I'm querying Solr the output is:

```
"text":["A, B, C"]
```

Could someone explain me how can I get the result as below?

```
"text":["A","B","C"]
```

Answer (score 0):

To do it in your DataImportHandler definition (since you've already added the [RegexTransformer](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#RegexTransformer)):

```
<field column="text" name="text" splitBy=", " />
```

Or do it in your field definition by using a TextField with a [Regular Expression Pattern Tokenizer](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/tokenizers.html#Tokenizers-RegularExpressionPatternTokenizer):

```
<analyzer>
  <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern=","/>
  <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

Comment: I tried both but it still doesnt't work. I'm using Solr 7.2.1 version.

Comment: So what does "doesn't work" mean? Does it give the wrong answer? Have you reindexed? Are you seeing any changes? Are you getting an error message? Are you sure your change has taken effect (i.e. have you reloaded/restarted Solr after making the change)? What does the "Analysis" page under Solr Admin tell you about how the field is being processed? "Does not work" does not help solve the problem :-)

Comment: I've reindexed Solr and when querying I am still getting output like: "text":["A, B, C"] when expected result is "text":["A","B","C"]

Comment: The second one won't change the actual text returned, only what's being indexed (i.e. which tokens are being generated at the backend level). I would think that the regex-version for DIH config would change the actual content stored, You might want to add `debug=true` or set `logLevel="debug"` to get [more information when running DIH](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_1/uploading-structured-data-store-data-with-the-data-import-handler.html).